# Show (or disprove) that $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Say that we have $\mathcal{T}$,which we know consists of $\emptyset$, $\mathbb{R}$, and every interval $(p,\infty)$ for $p \in \mathbb{R}$

I'm trying to show (or disprove) that $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

My guess is that it is a topology, but I'm struggling to prove the third of the three criteria in the definition of topology. Say $U$ is the finite set of elements of $\mathcal{T}$.

For the first condition, we are told that $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are in $\mathcal{T}$. We can logically infer that $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $\mathcal{T}$.

For the second condition, we want to prove that the intersection also belongs to $\mathcal{T}$.

For the first case, say $\emptyset \in U$. Then the intersection is also the empty set, which we know is in $\mathcal{T}$

In the second case, where every element in $U$ are equal to $\mathbb{R}$, then the intersection is $\mathbb{R}$, which belongs to $\mathcal{T}$.

In the third case, where only some elements of $U$ are equal to $\mathbb{R}$, we know the intersection is the intersection of non-equal elements (those not equal to to $\mathbb{R}$).

In the final case, where $U$ does not contain the empty set or $\mathbb{R}$, then each element of $U$ is of the form $(x_i, \infty)$ where $i$ is some index number less than the number of elements in $U$ and $x_i\in \mathbb{R}$. EDIT: I believe the intersection is $(min(x_i), \infty)\in \mathcal{T}$ for this case, because the interval will grow smaller with each intersection "added".

I'm just stumped on the third condition. I had thought that inclusion of unions would be easy to prove, by my thoughts go in circles. Does anyone have any suggestions for this?

Comment: Well, what is $(a,\infty)\cup(b,\infty)$? What about an infinite union of intervals of that form? Also remember that a topological space needs to be closed under arbitrary unions but only finite intersections.

Comment: "$U$ is finite." -- No it isn't. If there's an interval $(p,\infty) \in U$ for every real $p$, then it's uncountably infinite.

Comment: I meant to say that $U$ is the finite set of elements of $\mathcal{T}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. The "catch" is that a minimum of an arbitrary set of $x_i, i \in I$, the left end points of $(x_i, \infty)$, need not exist. But what *does* exist is the **infimum** $m=\inf\{x_i\mid i \in I\}$, which has a value $-\infty$ if the set of $x_i$ has no real lower bound, and is a real number (so $m \in \Bbb R$) if it has. This uses the order completeness of the reals. In both cases the definition of inf will show that $$\bigcup_{i \in I} (x_i,\infty) = (m, \infty)$$
where the latter set equals $\Bbb R$ in the $m=-\infty$ case, of course. In either case the union is a member of the topology so the third axiom holds.